# SQL: count occurrences of a guid in a "group"

Tags: sql

I have a family member relation in SQL, where I need to know if the same family person (a guid) shows up more than once pr. family (also a guid)

How do I count the family member guids in each family guid - or even better only return those family members where there are more than one (means same person twice or more)?

E.g.

| Familymember | Family |
| --- | --- |
| 7B815121-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 9617390F-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A |
| 7B815121-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 9617390F-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A |
| 1713A8C1-2E70-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 9617390F-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A |
| A773DFA2-8643-EB11-A812-000D3AACBC1D | 9617390F-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A |
| A773DFA2-8643-EB11-A812-000D3AACBC1D | 0B80A44B-3470-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A |
| CB0647AC-4470-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 0B80A44B-3470-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A |

Here I should have a count of 2 for '7B815121-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A' only, as the the other matches are from different family GUID's

Comment: `GROUP BY` can help

Comment: basically, you want to find duplicate records of a combination of `FamilyMember` and `Family` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should return the count of `familymember` that shows up more than once per `family`:

```
SELECT familymember, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY family, familymember 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Which gives:

| familymember | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 7B815121-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 2 |

The full count (not just duplicates) for each `family` is just:

```
SELECT family, familymember, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY family, familymember
```

| family | familymember | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0B80A44B-3470-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | A773DFA2-8643-EB11-A812-000D3AACBC1D | 1 |
| 0B80A44B-3470-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | CB0647AC-4470-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 1 |
| 9617390F-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 1713A8C1-2E70-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 1 |
| 9617390F-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 7B815121-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | 2 |
| 9617390F-7D6F-EB11-A812-000D3A22E46A | A773DFA2-8643-EB11-A812-000D3AACBC1D | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`select Familymember, count(Family) as count from table_name group by Familymember, Family;`

What this query does is it groups using both columns which means you will count those rows where both columns are the same.